# Flutter Horizontal ListView add lines under instead of infinite scroll

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The purpose of the application is to show many buttons that the user must select. Unfortunately infinite scrolling is not a user friendly tool here and it would be preferred to not have the user make any more actions than necessary.

As such, I need the horizontal ListView to be within one screen and expand under, adding new rows. I've tried adding a SizedBox, but the ListView row is still infinite and goes off screen.

```
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Test"),
  ),
  body: SizedBox(
      width: 300.0,
      child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: _rowWidgets.toList() // these are just IconButtons
             ),
          )
      );
```

The number of items may vary and I cannot divide the list into sublists consistently on all screens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need [Wrap](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) widget. Of course widget has no horizontal scrolling like in ListView. So you have to provide vertical scrolling to show a lot of buttons.

```
return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Test"),
          ),
          body: Center(
              child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  color: Colors.green,
                  width: 300.0,
                  child: Wrap(
                      spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
                      runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
                      children: List.generate(9, (i) => item(i.toString())).toList()
                  ),
              ),
          )
      );
```

Comment: thank you! with a little editing, I've managed to show the list exactly how I wanted. Very nice example